# Building Network Layer in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, ibm-blockchain

I am writing this to ask the question if we can build a network layer on top of the hyperledger fabric network.

I am actually working on a research project where I want to add encryption layer on the hyperedger fabric network.

I just want to know, if there are any starting points where I can work for this.

The basic idea is that, the encryption will be taking place in api layer and decryption will take place at peer level. If the decryption is successful, then only we should trigger the chaincode function. Can we do that ?

Please give your valuable suggestions on this.

Comment: The Fabric already has signature-based ACL and you can have TLS and mTLS, why would you do something custom?

Comment: We want to modify the endorsement process based on certain conditions, that's why we are working towards this.